# Can't figure out what's wrong with my SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running the following SQL query in PHP

```
   try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO doc SET type = 1, 
         candID = :candID, 
         userID = ".$_SESSION['userid'].", 
         filename = ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].", 
         date=date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')";

        $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':candID', $_POST['candid']);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error adding doc: ' . $e->getMessage();
        include $errorpage;
        exit();
    }
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Error adding doc: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':\xampp\tmp\phpD58B.tmp, date=date_format(curdate(),
>   '%d/%m/%Y')' at line 5

I can't quite figure out why I'm getting this error. Is there something wrong with my syntax that I'm missing?

Comment: Edit your question and add in the printed out value of `$sql`.  The answer will probably be obvious.  Hint:  string constants should be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Tip: to find syntax errors in SQL you first need to **see** the SQL you run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filename = ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].",` should be `filename = '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."',`

so the code should look like

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO doc SET type = 1, 
     candID = :candID, 
     userID = ".$_SESSION['userid'].", 
     filename = '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."', 
     date=date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')";

    $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':candID', $_POST['candid']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Error adding doc: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include $errorpage;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SET is used for UPDATE statements.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO doc  (type, candID, userID, finame, date) VALUES (1, :candID, :userID, :filename, :date)";

$s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->execute(array(':candID' => $_POST['candid'], ':userID' => $_SESSION['userid'], ':filename' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], ':date' => date('d/m/Y'));
```

Comment: In MySQL, pretty much anything goes...  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html and refer to the second syntax block at the top.

Comment: SET is for INSERT too. Used it in MySql and MSSql.

Comment: SET is not standard SQL, but ok MySQL supports it.
But using PDO prepare and then adding variables in the query..?

Comment: A valid point, @Martijn, and I can't say I particularly like the fact myself (as my day job requires me to actually use MySQL instead of something more standards-oriented).  I personally favor standards-compliant SQL queries for portability and readability.

Comment: @JustinBell MySQL also supports the standard :)